# Why does keyframe content with a diacritic cause additional whitespace?

Tags: angular, css, css-animations

On the home page of my Angular app, I have a couple of words which are changing from their definition. The change is defined in CSS:

```
.header-text:after {
   display: inline-block;
   content:'';
   animation: fide-in 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes fide-in {
   0% { content:'BLA'; opacity: 1; }
  50% { content:'BřA'; opacity: 1; }
}
```

My problem is with the word **'BřA'**. In Chrome, it is interpreted as **'Bř A'**. How can I get rid of this whitespace between 'ř' and 'A'?

Comment: Maybe font problem? Could you change to an other to check?

Comment: When I  put BřA directly in HTML, it works well. I tried the different font, but it is the same.

Comment: There is some kind of bug, Bř followed from 'a' to 'f' puts a space, Bř followed by from 'g' to 'x' renders correct

Comment: That's strange. Is there any workaround? (For ex. replace space character in CSS?)

Comment: I don't think it's a space, just the ř takes larger space than it should be. Also, I saw the same in safari, btw. Stranger that in stackblitz, it renders correctly, chrome or not : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pt9r9r?file=app%2Fapp.component.html. Didn't find the workaround, yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my workaround:

**CSS**

```
.header-text:after {
   display: inline-block;
   content:'';
   animation: fide-in 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes fide-in {
    0% {
        content: 'BLA';
    }
    50% {
        content: attr(content);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<p content="BřA" class="header-text"></p>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-19ziws?file=app%2Fapp.component.css)